# Shrinking SQL log file (ldf file)

Tags: sql, database

Here is my situation. I have a Database which is less than 100MG. Every night at 12 o'clock I get a backup from the database and keep it. Back up is done by Maintenance Plan and I have only checked 'Back Up Database (Full)' while creating the plan.

When I check the location of my mdf and ldf files, I can see my log file is much bigger than my mdf file (it is 10 gig) and I really don't think if that is necessary. I understand that Shrink is quite bad. I keep reading that log file grows till I back up transaction log. Does it mean, every night when I get a database backup, I should also check 'Back Up Database (Transaction Log)' ?

Sorry, I am not really good with database and it is quite confusing for me. I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this issue.

Comment: Yes, It means if you do a full data backup, do a transaction log backup to allow the sql server to reuse space within the transaction log file. Otherwise it'll just keep piling on and need more space because it's never "cleaned".

Comment: So if I backup the transaction log, the size of it becomes smaller? I tired it but the file is still big. How can I test it and see the results that it is actually working?

Comment: No - the size will not be smaller, but it'll free space within the file allowing for reuse. To reduce filesize you'll need to shrink the file, which is not advisable generally speaking.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That totally worked. I just got how that worked. How can I endorse your comments